# Trouble with password verification with salt/password/hash

Tags: php, hash

I've got one function to create a new user by generating a salt, appending it to password, and hashing the combination. I've got another function for user login verification, which takes the user's entered password and adds it to the user's unique salt, hashes, and compares to the encrypted password in the database (see comments throughout code).

I've echoed out all the important variables in the userValidate() function, but I can never get the hash+user password to match the encrypted password from the database. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Create user function:

```
function createNewUser($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, $address, $city, $state) {

    $conn = connectPDO();

    // Create a salt
    $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(64, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

    // Add salt to password
    $salted_password = $salt.$password;

    // Hash salt/password combination, to be added to "password" column of database
    $encrypted_password = hash('sha256', $salted_password);

    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`first-name`, `last-name`, `email-address`, 
                             `password`, `salt`, `address`, 
                             `city`, `state`, 
                             `registered-timedate`) VALUES (
                                :field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :field6, :field7, :field8, '$datetime')");

    return ($stmt->execute(array('field1' => $firstName, 
                         'field2' => $lastName, 
                         'field3' => $email, 
                         'field4' => $encrypted_password, 
                         'field5' => $salt, 
                         'field6' => $address, 
                         'field7' => $city, 
                         'field8' => $state)));
}
```

Validate user's login:

```
function userValidate($email, $user_password) {
    $conn = connectPDO();
    $sql = "SELECT `salt`,`password` FROM users where `email-address`='$email'";
    $q = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $q->fetch();

// Get the user's unique password salt
$salt = $row['salt'];

// Find the hashed salt/password combination
$database_password = $row['password'];

// Add salt to user's entered password and encrypt
$salted_password = $salt.$user_password;
$encrypted_password = hash('sha256', $salted_password);


// Compare the user password/salt hash to one stored in database
if($encrypted_password == $database_password) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Edit:

I've echo'd my vars on the registration page and I'm getting salts w/ many special characters like "J~Ã×/q,ó¸5 áczçvÁ!—Î/åÿâÑ^:h1Z¬MÃF¤º`„ù‹w¡ìe(Wúô    wW" which is not going in the database verbatim--goes in like "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". What data type should I use in my databsae for salts... and shouldn't salting/hashing/comparing generate the same two encrypted passwords for each (because the salts would still be the same?)

Comment: What is the storage type for your password / salt?  Does the password get cut off?  Also with PDO, you could just use ? to bind the variables since you don't seem to be using any special identifier with multiple fields.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out all the vars you use in the password construction to see if construction and re-construction match? Also, you should use PDO prepared statements and parameterised queries.

Comment: As for storing passwords. Using a salt is good, and using `sha256` is good but you can do better. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php important here is the `cost` option which allows you to specify how strong the encryption is. If you're not on PHP5.5 you can implement this manually by repeatedly hashing the password, consult a tutorial to verify how many times you should do this.

Comment: I think this line `$salted_password = $salt.$user_password;` should be `$salted_password = $salt.$database_password;` but can't be 100% sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, the database password should be the encrypted password. To get the encrypted password you must do: `hash(salt + pw)`

Comment: @Doge As I said, wasn't 100% sure. Am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Seriously, echo out your vars. This will show you if the correct things match, and also of you're getting a salt/password from the db, or even a result at all as you don't check errors/numrows etc.

Comment: Echo'd out vars--see edit. Thanks for helping

Comment: What type of DB are you using, what engine? Is the salt like that going in and coming out? If only out then DB needs addressing, if in too then probs an encoding issue (UTF-8 etc). Usually a varchar is adequate data type for such things.

Comment: MySQL - utf-8_general_ci. Column type is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you run into one of those two problems:

1. The database field for the hashed password is too small, the field must be able to store 64 characters.
2. There is a problem with the encoding of your salt, keep in mind that a salt generated with `mcrypt_create_iv()` is a binary string and can contain any character (even \0 characters).

Even if you can solve this problem, you have an unsafe scheme to store passwords (SHA256 is ways too fast for hashing passwords). Have a look at the PHP function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it will generate a BCrypt hash and takes care of the generation of a safe salt. The salt will be part of the resulting 62 character string, so there is no need to store the salt separately. There exist also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for older PHP versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```